# Overriding the combobox events

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it the wrong way I am doing this:
- first I created a class inheriting from Combobox and I am gonna override some events, so something like this:

```
public override void  SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

but it tells me : "There is no suitable method for override"

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override the method [`OnSelectedIndexChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.onselectedindexchanged.aspx) instead. The On[EventName] methods are the ones that raises the events. What you should do is to override that method, do the extra things you want to do and then call `base.OnSelectedIndexChanged(e)` when you want to raise the event:

```
protected override void OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    // do extra stuff here
    base.OnSelectedIndexChanged(e);
    // perhaps you want to do something after the event 
    // handlers have been invoked as well
}
```

Comment: +1 Good explanation, I didn't want to commit myself to saying those methods raised the events, I wasn't sure about that part :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot override events.  Instead you will find a method called OnSelectedIndexChanged, override this.